# (ANDROID PAYPAL SDK) How To Add PayPalReceiverDetails in PayPalPayment Method?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, paypal, paypal-sandbox

How can i add a PayPalReceiverDetails object in PayPalPayment object

as there is no method `getReceivers().add(PayPalReceiverDetails) in PayPalPayment,

Here is my Code:

```
PayPalPayment payPalPayment = new PayPalPayment();
payPalPayment.setCurrencyType("USD");
payPalPayment.setRecipient("example-merchant-1@paypal.com");
payPalPayment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal("1.00"));
payPalPayment.setPaymentType(PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_GOODS);
PayPalInvoiceData invoiceData = new PayPalInvoiceData();
invoiceData.setTax(new BigDecimal("0.00"));
invoiceData.setShipping(new BigDecimal("0.00"));
PayPalInvoiceItem invoiceItem = new PayPalInvoiceItem();
invoiceItem.setName("Samsung Gallexy S4 toy");
invoiceItem.setID("87238");
invoiceItem.setTotalPrice(new BigDecimal("1.00"));
invoiceItem.setUnitPrice(new BigDecimal("1.00"));
invoiceItem.setQuantity(1);
invoiceData.getInvoiceItems().add(invoiceItem);
payPalPayment.setInvoiceData(invoiceData);
payPalPayment.setMerchantName("The Store");
payPalPayment.setDescription("Pay Pal Example");
payPalPayment.setCustomID("1212121212");
payPalPayment.setIpnUrl("http://www.Test.com/ipn");
payPalPayment.setMemo("Test MEMO");
Intent chckoutIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(payPalPayment, MainActivity.this,new ResultDelegate());
startActivityForResult(chckoutIntent, requestCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created this , with a single Receiver .

```
    PayPalPayment newPayment = new PayPalPayment();
    newPayment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal(1));
    newPayment.setCurrencyType("USD");
    newPayment.setRecipient("validPaypalEmailaccount");
    newPayment.setMerchantName("My Company");
    Intent paypalIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout ( newPayment , PaypalDetailImplementation.this , adjustclass , new ResultDelegate()) ;

    startActivityForResult(paypalIntent,request );
```